cannot execute: required file not found, linking -lc wth ld command
So basically, I am working on a compiler ... long story short, I codegen and i want to use libc with the x86_64 AT&T Assembly. The object file is generated with 64bit elf architecture. I want to call printf from the assembly, so i use the following commad while generating obj and elf files :
as --64 examples/out/test.S -o examples/out/test.o && ld -lc examples/out/test.o -o examples/out/test

to link with libc. This command doesnt fail and produce an executable elf : examples/out/test, but when i try to run this file via ./examples/out/test, the following error appears :
bash: examples/out/test: cannot execute: required file not found

Here is the test.S file:
;#; This file was generated by the MZ compiler.
    .section .data
        b: .space 8
        a: .space 8
        fmt: .asciz "%lld"

    .global _start

    .section .text

_start: 
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp

    lea a(%rip), %rax
    movq $420, (%rax)
    lea b(%rip), %rax
    movq $42, (%rax)

    movq $42069, %rdx
    lea  fmt(%rip), %rcx
    call printf

    pop %rbp
    movl $0, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80

If there are any problems with calling conventions, please also correct them.
I am using Kali Linux (in WSL) on AMD x64 chip.
OBJDUMP of test.o:
examples/out/test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
examples/out/test.o
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000011:
HAS_RELOC, HAS_SYMS
start address 0x0000000000000000

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000040  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000015  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000080  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .bss          00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000095  2**0
                  ALLOC
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l       .data  0000000000000000 b
0000000000000008 l       .data  0000000000000000 a
0000000000000010 l       .data  0000000000000000 fmt
0000000000000000 g       .text  0000000000000000 _start
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 printf


RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE
0000000000000007 R_X86_64_PC32     .data+0x0000000000000004
0000000000000015 R_X86_64_PC32     .data-0x0000000000000004
000000000000002a R_X86_64_PC32     .data+0x000000000000000c
000000000000002f R_X86_64_PLT32    printf-0x0000000000000004

OBJDUMP of test:

examples/out/test:     file format elf64-x86-64
examples/out/test
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
start address 0x0000000000401020

Program Header:
    PHDR off    0x0000000000000040 vaddr 0x0000000000400040 paddr 0x0000000000400040 align 2**3
         filesz 0x00000000000001c0 memsz 0x00000000000001c0 flags r--
  INTERP off    0x0000000000000200 vaddr 0x0000000000400200 paddr 0x0000000000400200 align 2**0
         filesz 0x000000000000000f memsz 0x000000000000000f flags r--
    LOAD off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000400000 paddr 0x0000000000400000 align 2**12
         filesz 0x00000000000002d8 memsz 0x00000000000002d8 flags r--
    LOAD off    0x0000000000001000 vaddr 0x0000000000401000 paddr 0x0000000000401000 align 2**12
         filesz 0x0000000000000060 memsz 0x0000000000000060 flags r-x
    LOAD off    0x0000000000002000 vaddr 0x0000000000402000 paddr 0x0000000000402000 align 2**12
         filesz 0x0000000000000000 memsz 0x0000000000000000 flags r--
    LOAD off    0x0000000000002e98 vaddr 0x0000000000402e98 paddr 0x0000000000402e98 align 2**12
         filesz 0x0000000000000185 memsz 0x0000000000000185 flags rw-
 DYNAMIC off    0x0000000000002e98 vaddr 0x0000000000402e98 paddr 0x0000000000402e98 align 2**3
         filesz 0x0000000000000150 memsz 0x0000000000000150 flags rw-
   RELRO off    0x0000000000002e98 vaddr 0x0000000000402e98 paddr 0x0000000000402e98 align 2**0
         filesz 0x0000000000000168 memsz 0x0000000000000168 flags r--

Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
  HASH                 0x0000000000400210
  GNU_HASH             0x0000000000400228
  STRTAB               0x0000000000400278
  SYMTAB               0x0000000000400248
  STRSZ                0x000000000000001e
  SYMENT               0x0000000000000018
  DEBUG                0x0000000000000000
  PLTGOT               0x0000000000402fe8
  PLTRELSZ             0x0000000000000018
  PLTREL               0x0000000000000007
  JMPREL               0x00000000004002c0
  VERNEED              0x00000000004002a0
  VERNEEDNUM           0x0000000000000001
  VERSYM               0x0000000000400296

Version References:
  required from libc.so.6:
    0x09691a75 0x00 02 GLIBC_2.2.5

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .interp       0000000f  0000000000400200  0000000000400200  00000200  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .hash         00000014  0000000000400210  0000000000400210  00000210  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .gnu.hash     0000001c  0000000000400228  0000000000400228  00000228  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .dynsym       00000030  0000000000400248  0000000000400248  00000248  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .dynstr       0000001e  0000000000400278  0000000000400278  00000278  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .gnu.version  00000004  0000000000400296  0000000000400296  00000296  2**1
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  6 .gnu.version_r 00000020  00000000004002a0  00000000004002a0  000002a0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  7 .rela.plt     00000018  00000000004002c0  00000000004002c0  000002c0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  8 .plt          00000020  0000000000401000  0000000000401000  00001000  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  9 .text         00000040  0000000000401020  0000000000401020  00001020  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 10 .eh_frame     00000000  0000000000402000  0000000000402000  00002000  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 11 .dynamic      00000150  0000000000402e98  0000000000402e98  00002e98  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 12 .got.plt      00000020  0000000000402fe8  0000000000402fe8  00002fe8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 13 .data         00000015  0000000000403008  0000000000403008  00003008  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000              test.o
0000000000403008 l       .data  0000000000000000              b
0000000000403010 l       .data  0000000000000000              a
0000000000403018 l       .data  0000000000000000              fmt
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000              
0000000000402e98 l     O .dynamic       0000000000000000              _DYNAMIC
0000000000402fe8 l     O .got.plt       0000000000000000              _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
000000000040301d g       .data  0000000000000000              _edata
0000000000000000       F *UND*  0000000000000000              printf@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000403020 g       .data  0000000000000000              _end
0000000000401020 g       .text  0000000000000000              _start
000000000040301d g       .data  0000000000000000              __bss_start


If you hope to use the C runtime library, then you have to initialize the library.  Perhaps you should call your entry point "main" so you can pretend to be a C program.  Also, Linux passes the first two parameters in rdi and rsi, not rcx and rdx -- that's Windows.

Most likely your dynamic linker (PT_INTERP) is wrong. See it using readelf -e test. To fix it, either specify the correct one for ld using --dynamic-linker option, or use gcc instead (gcc -nostdlib -o test test.o -lc) and it will do it for you.

I was able to get your code to work by changing the entry point to main, changing the final "movq" to "lea" (which you already did,), and fixing the register convention to use rdi/rsi.

As @AndreyTurkin said gcc did it, Thx :). But it still doesnt print anything, if anyone can help ?

@TimRoberts: printf works from _start in a dynamically-linked executable without manually calling init functions, since the dynamic linker gives libc a chance to init itself.  The necessary change is to remove push %rbp because that misaligns the stack - _start isn't a function, rsp % 16 == 0 at the top of _start vs. rsp % 16 == 8 at the top of a function like main.  Also to follow the ABI you need xor %eax, %eax to set AL=0 right before the call, since printf is a variadic function.  But it will happen to work without that with glibc build by modern GCC.

Oh and also of course you need to call exit instead of making a raw _exit system call, since stdout is line buffered (TTY) or full buffered (redirected to anything else), and the text being printed doesn't include a newline.  If you also changed it to ret instead of syscall (or legacy 32-bit int 0x80 !!) when you changed it to main, that would have been what fixed that bug since returning from main is like calling exit(3), the libc function.  Yup, tried it and it worked (also fixing the calling convention for printf: RDI/RSI), built with gcc -nostartfiles -no-pie foo.s
